# Does $|t - s| < \epsilon$ imply $||t| -|s|| < \epsilon$ for $t,s \neq 0$ and $\epsilon>0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Say $t,s$ are non-zero real numbers and $\epsilon > 0$ is a positive real number where,

$|t - s| < \epsilon$

Then is is true that

$||t| -|s|| < \epsilon$.

If not what are the conditions required for

$||t| -|s|| \leq |t - s|$

Comment: By the reversed triangle inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's true.

\begin{equation}
|t| = |(t - s) + s| \leq |t - s| + |s|.
\end{equation}

Hence

\begin{equation}
|t| - |s| \leq |t - s|.
\end{equation}

Swapping the roles of $t$ and $s$ gives $|s| - |t| \leq |t - s|$, whence

\begin{equation}
||t| - |s|| \leq |t - s| \leq \varepsilon.
\end{equation}

Where the last inequality is by assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Using absolute value definition:

$$
\big||t|-|s|\big| = \begin{cases} |t| - |s| & \mbox{if } |s| \le |t|\\
|s| - |t| & \mbox{if } |t| < |s| \end{cases}
$$

Then
$$
\big||t|-|s|\big| = |t| - |s| \le |t - s| \quad \mbox{if}\quad |s| \le |t|
$$
$$
\big||t|-|s|\big| = |s| - |t| \le |s - t| = |t - s| \quad \mbox{if}\quad |t| \le |s|
$$